# Moving Camera from Point A to Point B On the Geometry Created Autodesk Viewer using three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying move my camera view state from point A to Point B.
For that I am creating a path using LineDashedMaterial in autodesk viewer and I am able to create and show the line from Point A to B.

here is the code

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(getBoundingBox([2112]).center(),
                    getBoundingBox([2109]).center());
material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({color: 0xFF0000,
                                          dashSize: 3,
                                          gapSize: 1,
                                          transparent: true,
                                          depthWrite: false,
                                          depthTest: true,
                                          });

checkLineDistance  = geometry.computeLineDistances();
geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate = true;
NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman().addMaterial('material', material, true);
line= new THREE.Line(geometry, material);   
NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneAfter.skipDepthTarget = true;
NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneAfter.skipIdTarget = true;                                       
NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneAfter.add(line);
```

which has resulted me with:
[image: this]

Now I am stuck with issue where I want to navigate or move my camera as per the direction of my line/path(A to B).
I am using a sample model right now consider this would be a building which have a room A and B.

2.Is there any way I can get all the vectors from where the line is passing I basically need position, target,and upVector for my camera movement

3.Is there any way I can get all the vectors or points from A to B using dbid in forge viewer api

4.I tried putting up Three.js with forge viewer but it seems difficult though.

[This](https://observablehq.com/@rveciana/three-js-object-moving-object-along-path) is what actually I am trying to achieve but instead of that moving geometry I need to show viewport in forge viewer

Answer (score 0):

The navigation system in Forge Viewer supports a smooth, linear interpolation into custom camera state using the `setRequestTransition` method, for example, like so:

```js
let newCameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
let newCameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
let fov = viewer.navigation.getHorizontalFov();
viewer.navigation.setRequestTransition(true, newCameraPosition, newCameraTarget, fov);
```

The default duration of this transition is 1 second, so if you had a list of vertices of a path that you would like to follow with the camera, you could do it with something like this:

```js
function followPath(viewer, vertices, delayMs) {
    let index = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (index >= vertices.length) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
        let newPos = vertices[index];
        let newTarget = vertices[index + 1];
        if (!newTarget) {
            let oldPos = viewer.navigation.getPosition();
            let oldTarget = viewer.navigation.getTarget();
            newTarget = new THREE.Vector3(
                newPos.x + (oldTarget.x - oldPos.x),
                newPos.y + (oldTarget.y - oldPos.y),
                newPos.z + (oldTarget.z - oldPos.z)
            );
        }
        viewer.navigation.setRequestTransition(true, newPos, newTarget, viewer.navigation.getHorizontalFov());
        index++;
    }, delayMs);
}

followPath(viewer, [
    new THREE.Vector3(10, 20, 30),
    new THREE.Vector3(40, 50, 60),
    new THREE.Vector3(70, 80, 90),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0)
], 2000);
```

If you need more flexibility (e.g., interpolating around curves, custom ease-in/ease-out, etc.), you can still use three.js or other animation libraries, and simply control the camera position and target yourself.

Comment: Thanks Petr this helped me more with controlling the camera, I had to pass vector3 array which is the problem I am looking for something which can get all the vector point in between point A to B so that camera position can travel through that Path as of now Camera Directly go to point B and skips all the elements eg Cabin A to Cabin D so while navigating toward point D  I have Cabin B and Cabin C

Comment: So for that I have created a Line from Point A to Point B and I need to follow the path of line or u can say all the vectors from where the line is going

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Cabin A" or "Cabin D"? In your screenshot you simply show a straight line between two endpoints. Are there any other "stops" along the line?

Comment: Yes I posted a sample screenshot. Let me explain you I am looking a solution which drives me through a path suppose if I am on floor 1 and I am looking for lift it should show me the direction using camera navigation to reach lift. That is the reason I created a line geometry

Comment: you mention this issue last post? did you use revit api? if you use revit api you can get points on the path through method Tessellate():
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/f95f3199-3251-c708-c5a3-a0e9ef95ecfa.htm
when you get points, you can get normal,....

Comment: No I am not getting those points in autodesk viewer, I confirmed with Autodesk Software Team and they said there is no such api where I can retrieve such information, the alternative which they suggested was adding a custom property which would hold the vector coordinates.

Comment: @PetrBroz I have achieved the needful and your above solutions worked well for what I was trying to do. :) only thing remaining now to add smooth transitions same as implemented in RCDB the reference which I have is written in react so had to rewrite in javascript